# ASP.NET WebForms - VB.NET and SignalR

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, signalr

This is my Hub code (very simple):

```
   Imports System
   Imports System.Web
   Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
   Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs
   Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
   Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging
   Imports System.Threading.Tasks
   
   Namespace SignalRChat
   
   Public Class ChatHub
         Inherits Hub

         Public Sub Send(userName As String, message As String)
             Clients.All.broadcastMessage(userName, message)
         End Sub

         End Class

    End Namespace
```

- This is my Aspx page code:

  ```
   Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
   Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
   Imports System.Threading.Tasks

   Public Class WebForm9
       Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


       Public Shared hubConnection As HubConnection
       Public Shared chatHubProxy As IHubProxy

       Public Sub MyChat_init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

           If IsPostBack = False Then
                hubConnection = New HubConnection("https://localhost:44343/")
                hubConnection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All
                hubConnection.TraceWriter = Console.Out
                chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub")
                hubConnection.Start().Wait()
           End If

           chatHubProxy.On(Of String, String)("broadcastMessage", Sub(ByVal userName As String, ByVal message As String)
                                                               Dim li As ListItem = New ListItem
                                                               li.Value = userName & " - " & message
                                                               li.Text = userName & " - " & message
                                                               ListBox1.Items.Add(li)

                                                           End Sub)
      End Sub

      Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
          chatHubProxy.Invoke("Send", "Io", "Messaggio")
      End Sub

    End Class
  ```

I made a lot of tries but always ended up with no result... I added the postback checking because I noticed I was having the connection to the hub starting and starting again on each button_click...

By the way, if I add in the same project a page with JScript code I can catch all the messages sent on the JScript code, but none of the messages sent from the html page is catched by the aspx codebehind...

It's really strange because if I take away the listbox.items.add method and I put a "MsgBox" instead, then it fires up and work... but I have found no way to manage the "messages" from my codebehind and so update controls on my page... Maybe it's a connection mistake? Did anyone of you has any experience with SignalR and WebForms with VB.NET codebehind?

Comment: Well any postback will stop everything (client code) on the page. The page travels up to the server. So, at that point any js client signlr events are not going to work. Then your code behind runs. And the full page + html AND ALSO the js in that page is now sent down back to the browser. The browser then displays that page, and THEN the js signalR code can now start to run again (that's why your post back stops the running of the signalR events). So, it not clear what you  plan to run with your .net button click + postback, but it will cause a full page lifecycle as I explained.

Comment: so, what this suggests is that you don't want a post back button here, but perhaps some js and a web method call, or so called ajax call from that button. But a postback is a full page travel and lifecycle process. So, if you going to have a button + postback, then your signalR code will stop, and when the page is re-sent back to client, then page displays, and that js code can start to run again. Without a post-back then code behind of course can't see or use any control on the page. You could (should) try placing your button inside of a update panel - that will avoid a full page post back.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I used an update panel con the page to prevent it from refreshing after the click, but the real problem is that I can't get message sent from other pages... The "On" method listen to the Hub broadcastMessage method but doesn't execute the listbox.items.add also if the message is sent from another html or aspx page... and this is really strange to me...

Comment: Don't believe that signalR sends any event to the code behind events for that page. And if it did send + trigger a event? Well, just like any ajax call, then viewstate and session() and all values and controls on that page are NOT available in the code behind (the browser page is STILL sitting client side.  Code behind can only use page values on a post back (or partial page post-back occurred). Client side code can certainly trigger + call a web method on that page. Not aware that SignalR runs any code behind events - but without a post back then that code has no use of page values.

Comment: So even if signalR did call any code behind - without a post back occurring, then that code can't touch or see anything in the web browser that is STILL sitting on the users desktop. So, you could however have a client side event do a post-back (say into that update panel).  Any server side code that just so happens to call code behind without a postback has not http context at all.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps, I have a working client code (for testing purposes) in VB.NET WinForms app. (My Hub is in C#):

Hub (ASP.NET Core in net5.0 - created using Gerald Versluis' tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDr0Hx67guk):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalR.Hubs;

public class OneHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(Message message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{message.SentDateTime} Sender : {message.SenderId} - {message.MessageText}");
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("MessageReceived", message);
    }
}
```

WinForms (net4.8):

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
Imports SignalRWinForms.Client.Messaging.Models

Public Class Form1

    Private connection As HubConnection
    Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        connection = New HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://192.168.1.230:5296/chat").Build()
connection.On(Of Messages)("MessageReceived", Sub(Messages)
                                                          Invoke(Sub()
                                                                     ReceiveMessage(Messages)
                                                                 End Sub)
                                                      End Sub)

        connection.StartAsync()
    End Sub


    Private Sub ReceiveMessage(msg As Messages)
        chatMessages.Text &= $"{Environment.NewLine}{msg.MessageText}"
    End Sub


    Private Async Sub btnSendMessage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSendMessage.Click
        Dim message = New Messages With {
                  .MessageText = txtMessage.Text,
                  .SenderId = 1111,
                  .ReceiverId = 2222,
                  .Token = "token",
                  .SentDateTime = DateTime.Now
              }
        Await connection.InvokeCoreAsync("SendMessage", args:={message})
        txtMessage.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub

End Class
```

Form1 is very simple - `chatMessages` label to populate messages, `txtMessage` textbox to write message and a `btnSendMessage` button.

Messages Class (common for both projects)

```
Public Class Messages
    Public Property SenderId As Integer
    Public Property ReceiverId As Integer
    Public Property MessageText As String
    Public Property Token As String
    Public Property SentDateTime As DateTime
End Class
```